# PSQL Query to fetch all values posted in a particular month

Tags: postgresql, datetime, psql

I'm trying to write a query to fetch the values in a particular month. I'm having problems with date conversion where psql stores the values as bigint.  My current query is below which works but I have to give the dates explicitly in the query. I'm looking for a more generic one (like select a month in gui and is converted to query).  For this I need to compare only the month and year for the date field (to accommodate the leap years). timetocomplete and executedtime are timestamp (bigint) columns and I'm trying to calculate the no. of hours worked during the month in executedtime

```
select sum(s.timetocomplete/1000*1/3600)
from requestdetail s
where
    ('2015-10-31 23:59:59'::timestamp at time zone 'UTC' > TO_TIMESTAMP(executedtime / 1000))
    and
    TO_TIMESTAMP(executedtime / 1000) < '2015-10-31 23:59:59'::timestamp at time zone 'UTC'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the October, 2015 month:

```
with work_month (work_month) as ( values
    ('2015-10-01'::date)
)
select sum(s.timetocomplete / 1000 / 3600)
from requestdetail s cross join work_month
where
    work_month <= to_timestamp(executedtime / 1000)
    and
    to_timestamp(executedtime / 1000) < work_month + interval '1 month'
```

Simpler version:

```
select sum(timetocomplete / 1000 / 3600)
from requestdetail
where date_trunc('month', to_timestamp(executedtime / 1000)) = '2015-10-01'
```

Comment: Syntax error near 'crosstab'. Does that mean that function is not available in my installation?

Comment: @Ravi It is `cross join`. Corrected

Comment: Thanks. It works.  Just for my info, don't we have something like `to_timestamp (executedtime/1000,'MM') == '10'` in postgres?  This solution looks like we go around the head to reach the nose :-).  I'm new to pgsql and I feel things are not straight forward in postgres as in mysql

Comment: @Ravi Check the simpler version

Comment: Thanks. It works and is simple enough.  But why do we give `'2015-10-01'` when we are just comparing `date_trunc('month',timestamp)`? I tried this date_trunc in a similar way but with `'10'` to compare instead of `'2015-10-01'` and it did not work.

Comment: @Ravi `date_trunc` returns a complete `timestamp` although the function name suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **epoch()** function for convert datetime to seconds and then calculate and compare these values

Comment: how do I do that for any particular month?  can you give a query example?  I have tried the postgres doc examples in vain.